# Digester rules for a string list

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-digester

I have an xml doc that looks something like this:

```
<response>
  <total>1000</total>
  <warning>warning1</warning>
  <warning>warning2</warning>
</response>
```

My object looks like this:

```
public class Response {
    private BigDecimal total;

    private List<String> warnings=new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getWarnings() {
        return warnings;
    }

    public void setWarnings(List<String> warnings) {
        this.warnings = warnings;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(BigDecimal total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public void addWarning(String warning) {
        warnings.add(warning);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to map it like this:

```
Digester digester = new Digester();
digester.setValidating( false );
digester.addObjectCreate( "response", Response.class );
digester.addBeanPropertySetter( "response/total", "total" );
digester.addObjectCreate("response/warning","warnings", ArrayList.class);
digester.addCallMethod("response/warning", "add", 1);
digester.addCallParam("response/warning", 0);
ret = (Rate)digester.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
```

However, I can't get it to populate the list.  The total does get set correctly.  For what it's worth, I have no control over the XML, but can change my Response object.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already had `addWarning` method in your `Response` class and `warnings` is initialized too.
Just rewrite your rules:

```
    Digester digester = new Digester();
    digester.setValidating( false );
    digester.addObjectCreate("response", Response.class );
    digester.addBeanPropertySetter("response/total", "total" );
    digester.addCallMethod("response/warning", "addWarning", 1);
    digester.addCallParam("response/warning", 0);
```

And that's all.